# How to append two dictionaries using user input but the second dictionary should be the value and First dictionary should be key

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop, append

```
no_sub = int(input("Enter Number Of Subjects : "))`
no_mark = int(input("Enter how many student's marks do you want to add : "))

for i in range (0,no_sub):
    sub_name = input("Enter Subject Names : ")

    for j in range (0,no_mark):
        stud_marks = input("Enter student's Marks : ")
        marks[sub_name] = stud_marks

print(marks)
```

In this program the expected output is `{'Phy':[65,66,70,45],'Eng':[90,96,89,76],'Chem':[67,45,56,70]}` but when I try to merge these dictionaries using user input I am getting this output

```
Enter Number Of Subjects : 3
Enter how many student's marks do you want to add : 4
Enter Subject Names : Phy
Enter student's Marks : 46
Enter student's Marks : 45
Enter student's Marks : 27
Enter student's Marks : 67
Enter Subject Names : Eng
Enter student's Marks : 44
Enter student's Marks : 23
Enter student's Marks : 75
Enter student's Marks : 81
Enter Subject Names : Maths
Enter student's Marks : 68
Enter student's Marks : 35
Enter student's Marks : 36
Enter student's Marks : 86
{'Phy': '67', 'Eng': '81', 'Maths': '86'}
```

please help , I'm trying to fix this sice hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `marks[sub_name] = stud_marks` use list and append input there:

```py
no_sub = int(input("Enter Number Of Subjects : "))
no_mark = int(input("Enter how many student's marks do you want to add : "))

marks = {}
for i in range(no_sub):
    sub_name = input("Enter Subject Names : ")

    for j in range(no_mark):
        stud_marks = input("Enter student's Marks : ")
        marks.setdefault(sub_name, []).append(int(stud_marks))

print(marks)
```

Prints:

```
Enter Number Of Subjects : 2
Enter how many student's marks do you want to add : 2
Enter Subject Names : A
Enter student's Marks : 1
Enter student's Marks : 2
Enter Subject Names : B
Enter student's Marks : 3
Enter student's Marks : 4
{'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro , I literally tried to first append the user input into a list and then convert the list into a dictionary using iteration and then copy that dictionary and save its input and then tried to append it , but here it is ,  you just changed 1 single line

Answer (score 0):

You can easily generate a defaultdict and keep appending to it.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def add_marks():
  # create a defaultdict dt.
  dt = defaultdict(list)
  for i in range(3):
    temp = input()
    if temp.isalpha():
      # print(temp)
      for j in range(2):
        dt[temp].append(int(input()))
        # print(dt)
    else:
      print("please only enter letters for subjects names")
      return dt
  return dt

print(add_marks())


Output:

defaultdict(list, {'math': [80, 90], 'phy': [60, 70], 'social': [87, 96]})
```

Comment: thanks for that , It'll be very helpful for my future projects